# smooth quandle transitive

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Let $G$ be a commutative Lie group and let $T \in \operatorname{Aut}(G)$ be an automorphism of the Lie group. We put $x * y=T x+(1-T) y$ for $x, y \in G$, and then $(G, T)$ is a smooth quandle. We call $(G, T)$ an Alexander quandle and denote it by $G_{T}$ , if $T$ is a multiplication by a scalar $a$, we simply denote it by $G_{a} .$
I need to show that $G_{T}$ is transitive if and only if the endomorphism $1-T$ on $G$ is surjective. I get stuck in this question.

Comment: what is the qn?

Comment: What is quandle ?

Comment: Why all the diff geo/diff top tags? And what are your efforts at the question, presuming there is one?

Comment: A quandle is a pair of a set $X$ and a binary operator $*: X \times X \ni(x, y) \mapsto$ $x * y \in X$ satisfying three axioms:

(Q1) For any $x \in X, x * x=x .$

(Q2) For any $y \in X$, the map $s_{y}: X \ni x \mapsto x * y \in X$ is a bijection.

(Q3) For any $x, y, z \in X,(x * y) * z=(x * z) *(y * z)$.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Answer (score 3):

We say that $X$ is transitive if the action of $\operatorname{Inn}(X)$ on $X$ is transitive, with $\operatorname{Inn}(X)$ is the sub group of the $Aut(X)$ generated by $s_y$ $(y \in X)$ and called the inner antonorphisma group.

Return to my question, we take the action of $\operatorname{Inn}(X)$ on $G$ defince by
$$
\begin{aligned}
Inn(G) \times G & \longrightarrow G \\
(y,  x)&\longrightarrow y* x=s_y(x)=T{y}+(1-T) x
\end{aligned}
$$
such that
$$\begin{aligned} \text { $s_y$ :  }\;\;\; G  & \longrightarrow G \\ x & \longrightarrow s_y(x)=y * x \end{aligned}$$

if $G$ is transitive then $H$ is transitive, for all $x, y$ for there is $z$ on $\operatorname{Inn}(X)$ such that $$x=y * z=s_{y}(z)=T{y}+(1-T) z$$ then $$(1-T)z=x-T y $$

then $(1-T)$ is surjective.

Conversaly:
we have $T \in Aut(G)$ and $\forall x, y \in G$,  $x-Ty \;\in G$, and $1 -T$ surjective then  $\exists z \in G$ sush that
$$
(1-T) z=x-T y $$
then $$ x=y * z . \quad \forall x, y \in G $$
Hence G is transitive.